# Second order hyperbolic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

Consider $\Omega$ a regular domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I'm looking for criterion to ensure the well posedness (or not)  of this hyperbolic equation: find $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that 
$$div(A\nabla u)=f\in\mathbb{L}^2(\Omega)$$
in which $A$ is $2\times2$ symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $a_1$ and $b_1$ such that $a_1b_1<0$.

Comment: no, the matrix is not positive definite;

Comment: f and u are scalar functions